# Trying to figure out how to using printf without PUSH & POP; which do not exist in ARMv8. Seems like a lot of extra work

Tags: assembly, arm64

Trying to figure out how to using printf without PUSH & POP; which do not exist in ARMv8.  Seems like a lot of extra work.

What am I missing?

## armv8   #printf

```
 12 main:
 13         nop
 14         mov x12, 0xff
 15         mov x1, x12
 16         1:
 17         mov x2, x12
 18         2:
 19
 20         mul x3, x1, x2
 21
 22         bl write                // triggers save of next location in x30
 23
 24         subs x2, x2, 1
 25         bpl 2b
 26         subs x1, x1, 1
 27         bpl 1b
 28
 29 exit:
 30         mov x8, #93             // exit see /usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h
 31         svc 0
 32
 33 write:
 34         stp x29,x30,[sp]        // save FP and LR
 35         stp x1,x2,[sp,(8*3)]    // store pair of regs on stack
 36         str x12,[sp,(8*5)]      // store single reg on stack
 37         ldr w0,=fmt
 38         bl printf
 39         ldr x12,[sp,(8*5)]
 40         ldp x1,x2,[sp,(8*3)]
 41         ldp x29,x30,[sp]
 42         ret                     // return from function
```

....

```
sample out:
255 * 255 =  65025
255 * 254 =  64770
255 * 253 =  64515
255 * 252 =  64260
255 * 251 =  64005
255 * 250 =  63750
255 * 249 =  63495
```

Comment: armv4, v5, v6, v7 dont have a push or pop either, the assembler might support a pseudo instruction for load and store multiple.  same goes for thumb.

Comment: Yes. That is technically correct. Pseudo instructions are nice.

Comment: so armv8 is no different they have at least one for pushing and one for popping.   I think they intentionally do not want a very long executing stm or ldm that has to be waited on nor restarted with an interrupt.  I didnt read up if they restart stp/ldp or let it run then interrupt after, i would assume they abort the instruction as with cache misses you can be in the hundreds of clock cycles.

Comment: I guess point being was they (gnu assembler perhaps arm ads) didnt have push and pop on arm instructions for armv4 until the thumb tools matured and then I think they tolerated it for arm.  or perhaps I never tried, the tools were pretty picky at first, had to have three registers defined for arm instructions add r0,r0,r1 couldnt do thumb style add r0,r1 until later, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
stp x29,x30,[sp]        // save FP and LR
stp x1,x2,[sp,(8*3)]    // store pair of regs on stack
str x12,[sp,(8*5)]      // store single reg on stack
```

Since [the AArch64 ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0055b/IHI0055B_aapcs64.pdf) uses a full-descending stack - i.e. it grows downwards, and SP points *at* the last entry rather than below it - what this code does is trash 5 of the bottom 6 entries of your current stack contents (sparing a gap in the middle, for some reason). You happen to have got lucky via the combination of being at zero call depth in `main()`, then invoking the `exit` syscall directly, so you never notice the damage.

You need to adjust SP accordingly to make room for things you're pushing, then move it back up again when you pop them off, which is easily done with standard addressing modes<sup>*</sup>:

```
stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!  // pre-indexed with writeback 'push'
ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16    // post-indexed 'pop'
```

Furthermore, SP has to remain 16-byte aligned, so if you've got an odd number of registers to preserve before a call, you can simply push/pop `xzr` to make up the difference.

<sub>* hey, you could even [write some macros](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/include/asm/assembler.h?h=v4.5#n29) if you *really* want to pretend.</sub>

Comment: Excellent! Yeah... I got lucky in spite of poor stack preservation! Thanks for the links, I was just looking for the ABI.

Comment: Attached is a link to some gdb values that illustrate visually why my first code was bad; in spite of it working. I'm just using define hook-stop x/16xg $sp to show stack values after each stop. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e6_4J_dWRb9NeRBEwIq0B4KMY2Hk0oFus1mpd1Wsxec/edit?usp=sharing